# git log --cherry-pick A..B - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-log

In order to find commits on branch `working` not merged/picked to `master` yet I'm running

```
git log --format="%h %aN %ai %f" --cherry-pick --no-merges master..working
```

as learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710894/using-git-show-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-the-others).

But as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807522/why-is-git-log-cherry-pick-not-removing-equivalent-commits) I'm finding commits which are on `master` *and* `working` only varying in commit IDs due to cherry-picking.

Neither `working` has been merged to `master` nor vice versa.

Even when I manually cherry-pick a commit from `working` to `master` it will show up running the above command.

Acutally `--cherry-pick` seems to have no effect at all, as `|wc` show.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:

Actually both ElpieKay and torek are right and my initial command would have worked, too. Unfortunately I did not know we're using some "cherry-pickish" magic I did not know about which alters commits after cherry-picking

.

Comment: Try `master...working`. I'm afraid you missed one dot.

Comment: `A..B` is shorthand for `^A B` (see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) - `...` seems to be for symmetrical diffs, ie it also shows commits on `master` which are not on `working`. Nevertheless it shows cherry-picked commits as well.

Comment: @ElpieKay: strangely, when I try to come up with a reproducible minimal example, unsing `...` cherry-picked commits don't show up, indeed. But unfortunately those which are on `master` only show up, too. Nevertheless in my actual project checkout cherry-picked commits _do_ show up (using `...`) even when `git patch-id` tells me, they are the same..

Comment: FWIW : I found I had a better view of what is marked as cherry-pickable or not using :  `git log --graph --cherry-mark --boundary --format="..." A...B` (`cherry-mark` will still mention commits that *are* cherry-picked, and indicate them with a `=`, the `--graph --boundary` pair makes clearer what commit is on what side of the graph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [ElpieKay mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319896/git-log-cherry-pick-a-b-what-am-i-doing-wrong#comment115480015_65319896), you need the three-dot notation.  However, just adding the three-dot notation is not sufficient: you will also want to add `--left-only` or `--right-only` (depending on which side of the symmetric difference you put the `A` and `B` parts, of `A...B`, on).

Note:

> In order to find commits on branch `working` not merged/picked to `master` yet [I used] `master..working`

So here, you'd want `--right-only master...working`.  You can keep `--no-merges` as well.  If the merges only show up on `master` you don't actually need `--no-merges`, but it's probably harmless.  Note, however, that `--no-merges` completely eliminates *all* merges, regardless of their patch-IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Before Git 2.30.1 (Q1 2021), when more than one commit with the same patch ID appears on one side, "[`git log --cherry-pick A...B`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b69bed22c59fa08848bd7ffa5fbfacc0b62fcd48/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L231)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry-pick))</sup> did not exclude them all when a commit with the same patch ID appears on the other side.
Now it does (again, with Git 2.31, Q1 2021).

See [commit c9e3a4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9e3a4e76d57b03170118aa67054af0b81e7f507) (12 Jan 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b69bed2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b69bed22c59fa08848bd7ffa5fbfacc0b62fcd48), 25 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`patch-ids`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9e3a4e76d57b03170118aa67054af0b81e7f507): handle duplicate hashmap entries
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Arnaud Morin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> This fixes a bug introduced in [dfb7a1b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfb7a1b4d0dafd53bf3980b3bd90668bf8d2a27f) ("`patch-ids`: stop using a hand-rolled hashmap implementation", 2016-07-29, Git v2.10.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd610aeda684e42d3933a719cbd59ffbcdfdbcaa)) in which
>
> ```
> git rev-list --cherry-pick A...B
> ```
>
> will fail to suppress commits reachable from `A` even if a commit with matching patch-id appears in `B`.
>
> Around the time of that commit, the algorithm for "`--cherry-pick`" looked something like this:
> 0. Traverse all of the commits, marking them as being on the left or right side of the symmetric difference.
>
> 1. Iterate over the left-hand commits, inserting a patch-id struct for each into a hashmap, and pointing `commit->util` to the patch-id struct.
> 2. Iterate over the right-hand commits, checking which are present in the hashmap.
>    If so, we exclude the commit from the output *and* we mark the patch-id as "seen".
> 3. Iterate again over the left-hand commits, checking whether `commit->util->seen` is set; if so, exclude them from the output.
>
> At the end, we'll have eliminated commits from both sides that have a matching patch-id on the other side.
> But there's a subtle assumption here: for any given patch-id, we must have exactly one struct representing it.
> If two commits from `A` both have the same patch-id and we allow duplicates in the hashmap, then we run into a problem:
>
> - a. In step 1, we insert two patch-id structs into the hashmap.
> - b. In step 2, our lookups will find only one of these structs, so only
>   one "seen" flag is marked.
> - c. In step 3, one of the commits in A will have its `commit->util->seen`
>   set, but the other will not. We'll erroneously output the latter.
>
> Prior to [dfb7a1b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfb7a1b4d0dafd53bf3980b3bd90668bf8d2a27f), our hashmap did not allow duplicates.
> Afterwards, it used `hashmap_add()`, which explicitly does allow duplicates.
>
> At that point, the solution would have been easy: when we are about to add a duplicate, skip doing so and return the existing entry which matches.
> But it gets more complicated.
>
> In [683f17e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/683f17ec440afafd2b375fd1b7a80a1aca219b4f) ("`patch-ids`: replace the seen indicator with a commit pointer", 2016-07-29, Git v2.10.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd610aeda684e42d3933a719cbd59ffbcdfdbcaa)), our step 3 goes away entirely.
> Instead, in step 2, when the right-hand side finds a matching `patch_id` from the left-hand side, we can directly mark the left-hand `patch_id->commit` to be omitted.
> Solving that would be easy, too; there's a one-to-many relationship of patch-ids to commits, so we just need to keep a list.
>
> But there's more.
> Commit [b3dfeeb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3dfeebb92630c54db1e4f03dbcff0e05208c4c1) ("`rebase`: avoid computing unnecessary patch IDs", 2016-07-29, Git v2.10.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd610aeda684e42d3933a719cbd59ffbcdfdbcaa)) built on that by lazily computing the full patch-ids.
> So we don't even know when adding to the hashmap whether two commits truly have the same id.
> We'd have to tentatively assign them a list, and then possibly split them apart (possibly into N new structs) at the moment we compute the real patch-ids.
> This could work, but it's complicated and error-prone.
>
> Instead, let's accept that we may store duplicates, and teach the lookup side to be more clever.
> Rather than asking for a single matching patch-id, it will need to iterate over all matching patch-ids.
> This does mean examining every entry in a single hash bucket, but the worst-case for a hash lookup was already doing that.
>
> We'll keep the hashmap details out of the caller by providing a simple iteration interface.
> We can retain the simple `has_commit_patch_id()` interface for the other callers, but we'll simplify its return value into an integer, rather than returning the `patch_id` struct.
> That way they won't be tempted to look at the "commit" field of the return value without iterating.